# Perl insert new element into array subarray

Tags: xml, arrays, perl, hash

Hello I am trying to insert a new element so that I go from  this

```
   <explicit-group name="CDEV">
      <aip-address>1.1.1.1</aip-address>
      <aip-address>2.2.2.2</aip-address>
      <aip-address>3.3.3.3</aip-address>
```

To this

```
   <explicit-group name="CDEV">
      <aip-address>1.1.1.1</aip-address>
      <aip-address>2.2.2.2</aip-address>
      <aip-address>3.3.3.3</aip-address>
      <aip-address>99.99.99.254</aip-address>
```

The code I have is as follows but I have been reading about references and de referencing for two days and still cant get it. Am I trying to do something impossible or can someone show me how.

Thanks!

```
use strict;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
my $xs = XML::Simple->new(
  XMLDecl => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>',
  forcearray => [ 'item' ],
  keyattr    => {   },
  rootname   => 'SG-distribution',
);

my $opt = $xs->XMLin(\*DATA);


push @{ $opt->{'sa-coller'}->{'explicit-group'} } , { {'CDEV'}->{'aip-address'} };

print Dumper($opt);
print $xs->XMLout($opt);

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SG-distribution>
  <sa-coller name="W8-C1" enabled="true" host="localhost" port="99">
    <ip-group name="home" ipAddressMask="192.168.0.*" match="glob"/>
    <ip-group name="home2" ipAddressMask="10.0.0.*" match="glob"/>
    <explicit-group name="CDEV">
      <aip-address>1.1.1.1</aip-address>
      <aip-address>2.2.2.2</aip-address>
      <aip-address>3.3.3.3</aip-address>
    </explicit-group>
    <explicit-group name="HYU"/>
    <explicit-group name="JUN"/>
  </sa-coller>
</SG-distribution>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array with four element representing each `explicit_group` element. You want to identify the one whose name attribute is `CDEV`. Since they're not indexed by name (but by position), so you'll need to iterate over the array to find the right element.

```
for my $explicit_group (@{ $opt->{'sa-coller'}{'explicit-group'} }) {
  if ($explicit_group->{name} eq 'CDEV') {
     push @{ $explicit_group->{'aip-address'} }, '99.99.99.254';
   }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou ikegami this is exactly what I was trying to do.